# One column floated to the left and other fill the rest of page

Tags: css, static, width, fill

The basic idea is to have one div floated to the left with static width and have the another floated to the right filling with its width the rest of the page. How can I achive this ?

So far I have used in css something like this:

```
width: calc( 100% - 325px );
```

but I am looking for the best cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make left to **float: left** and the rest to **overflow: hidden** like this:

```
.left {float: left; width: 200px;}
.full {overflow: hidden; width: auto;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/DdaPs/

You can also make them even by using ***display: table***.....but you question was the one above.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly it would be (with a gap of 1em in between):

```
.col1 {float:left;
width:325px;
margin :0 1em;
}
.col2 {overflow:hidden;
margin-right:1em;
}
```

Comment: to include old IEs, add zoom:1; to .col2

Answer (score 0):

a simple trick using margin

```
.sidebar{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 325px;
}

.container{
   margin-left: 325px;
}
```

a quick example

http://jsfiddle.net/s8nFX/1/

Comment: idem , abused of absolute positionning

Answer (score -1):

If you always know the width of your left column, something like this would be best:

```css
 #left_column
    {
        width: 325px;
        float: left;
    }
    #right_column
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 325px; right:0;
    }
```

Comment: position:absolute is a bad idea , it takes content out of the flow when unecessary here

Comment: It is not necessarily a bad idea. It depends on how the rest of the page is set up. It also works consistently across older browsers which was requested in the question.

Comment: then you could use a table as well since it's bullet proof cross browser. Honnestly, avoid as much as possible absolute position. You cannot have a hand on it. You never know what/how much content it will hold and where it's going to be seen (or maybe hidden or hidden everything else )

Comment: I disagree that it should be avoided. It is useful in places. You just have to plan around it and ensure you know how to use it correctly. I use it fairly often and have never had any issues with it.

Comment: i meant 'avoid as much as possible'. web page are suppose to be flexible , absolute or fixed are not really :) today, we have (for over ten years) display:table and now flex showing up , layout(the nasty ;) "haslayout" since IE5.5). absolute should really comme last option

Comment: Fair enough, and I do agree that your solution is better, it is one I would not have considered. But I still maintain that there is nothing wrong with my answer. Perhaps if there were elements underneath it would not be suitable. But that was not a criteria of the question asked.

Comment: my real point is that "absolute poitionning" as advised solution to a 'rookie' (or not)  in CSS , doesn't help. Let him deal first with flow and layout has more use.